# Does Webots use at most one core of the CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, webots

I found that when I open multiple Webots, the maximum CPU utilization of each Webots in FAST mode is about 100. I want to know if each Webots uses up to 1 core of the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Webots uses a single core. In the `WorldInfo` node, there is an `optimalThreadCount` parameter which you can increase to use multiple cores. However, please carefully read the parameter description as it will not necessarily speed up the simulation.